# M. Isaac lemma $1.13$

Tags: representation-theory

The following is an excerpt from M. Isaac:s "Character theory of finite groups" (lemma $1.13$ in chapter $1$).

> Let $V = \sum_{} \cdot W_i$ be a direct sum of $A$-modules with $W_i$ irreducible for all $W_i$. Let $M$ be an irreducible $A$-module.

Then

> a) $M(V)$ is an $E_V(A)$-submodule of $V$.

Comments on the notation:

As I have understood it, $E_V(A)$ is the centralizer of $A_V$ where $A_V$ is the image of $A$ under the map $f:A \to \text{End}(V)$. I.e. it is the centralizer of all maps $x_V:V \to V$ defined explicitly by $v \longmapsto vx$ where $x \in A$.

$M(V)$ is the sum of all submodules of $V$ which are isomorphic to $M$ (supposedly as $A$-modules).

> *Proof of a)*: Let $s \in E_A(V)$. We need to show that $M(V)s \subseteq M(V)$. It suffices to show that if $W \subseteq V$ and $W \cong M$, then $Ws \subseteq M(V)$. This is sufficient because $M(V)$ is the sum of such $W$. If $Ws = 0$, there is nothing to prove; if $Ws \neq 0$, then since $Ws$ is a homomorphic image of the irreducible module $W$, we have $Ws \cong W \cong M$, thus $Ws \subseteq M(V)$.

I am having a really hard time understanding the structure of this proof. Why do we want to show that $M(V)s \subseteq M(V)$. And why does it suffice to show that if $W \subseteq V$ and $W \cong M$ then $Ws \subseteq M(V)$?

Edit: I believe I understand the first part, i.e. we want to show that if $m \in M(V)$ then $ms \in M(V)$, otherwise it is clearly not a (right) $E_V(A)$-module.

Edit 2: Since $M(V) = \sum_{l} W_l$ where $W_l \cong M$, as $A$-modules, if I am correct. Hence this explains why it is enough to show that if $W \subseteq V$ and $W \cong M$ then $Ws \subseteq M(V)$, since then it follows that if $(W_l)s \subseteq M(V)$ for all $l$ (in the sum $M(V)$), then $\sum_{l} (W_l)s \subseteq M(V)$, if I am not mistaken, which would imply that $M(V)s \subseteq M(V)$.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I understand it correctly, i.e. we want to show that if $m \in M(V)$ then $ms \in M(V)$, otherwise it is clearly not a (right) $E_V(A)$-module.

Since $M(V) = \sum_{l} W_l$ where $W_l \cong M$, as $A$-modules, if I am correct. Hence this explains why it is enough to show that if $W \subseteq V$ and $W \cong M$ then $Ws \subseteq M(V)$, since then it follows that if $(W_l)s \subseteq M(V)$ for all $l$ (in the sum $M(V)$), then $\sum_{l} (W_l)s \subseteq M(V)$, if I am not mistaken, which would imply that $M(V)s \subseteq M(V)$.

If $Ws \neq 0$, then I believe it is a fact that if $\ker s|_W \neq 0$, we get a submodule of $W$, but $W$ is irreducible (contradiction!). Hence $\ker s|_W = 0$. Since $s|_W$ agrees with $s$ on $W$, we get that $Ws \cong W \cong M$, since $W \cong Ws|_w = Ws$. I am here using the fact that for homomorphisms $f:A \to B$, it is the case that if $f$ is injective, then $f(A) \cong A$.

Unless I am mistaken, this becomes an $A$-module isomorphism, since $s \in E_V(A)$ so $s$ commutes with everything on the form $x_V:V \to V$ where $x_V(w) = wx$. Hence $(wx)(s) = (wx_V)(s) = w(x_Vs) = w(sx_V) = (ws)x_V = (ws)x$ for $x \in A$ and $w \in W$.